# Resize image from Rackspace container, save image in memory as new image in container?

Tags: php, image, resize, rackspace-cloud

I have a script that upload an image file to rackspace container, what I want to happen after that is

1. Create a copy of that image file.
2. Put the file into memory and resize the image.
3. Upload the file to the rackspace container with new file name.

Trouble is I'm not sure how to take the resampled image in memory and upload to rackspace container. Here is code.

```
            $objectStoreService = $client->objectStoreService(null, 'IAD');
            $container = $objectStoreService->getContainer(IMAGE_CONTAINER_NAME);
            $fileData = fopen($_FILES['file-0']['tmp_name'], 'r');
            $uniqid = uniqid();
            $new_file_path = $uniqid."/".$_FILES['file-0']['name'];
            $sm_file_path = $uniqid . "/" . 'sm_' .$_FILES['file-0']['name'];
            // Upload filepath to database
            $user->upload_profile_pic($new_file_path, $sm_file_path);
            $result = $container->uploadObject($new_file_path, $fileData);
            $new_file_path = IMAGE_CONTAINER_LINK."/".$new_file_path;

            // Make Thumbnail of original image
            $percent = 0.5; // percentage of resize

            // Image to be changed.
            $original_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($new_file_path);
            list($width, $height) = getimagesize($new_file_path);

            $new_width = $width * $percent;
            $new_height = $height * $percent;

            //  Temporary blank image in memory of height/width
            $tmp_image = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);

            // Copies the source image and copies into it the blank image and resamples it.
            imagecopyresampled($tmp_image, $original_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height);


            // Save the image in memory
            imagejpeg($tmp_image, NULL, 100);

            // read the file
            // Not sure how to put image in memory to rackspace cloud.
            $fileData = fopen($tmp_image, 'r');
            $tmp_image = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($new_file_path));
            $fileData = fopen($tmp_image, 'r');
            $result = $container->uploadObject($sm_file_path, $fileData);
            $response = array('image_path' => $new_file_path);
            header('HTTP/1.1 201 Created');
            echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: According the docs of [`imagecreatetruecolor`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.imagecreatetruecolor.php), this function returns a file resource - which means you can pass it directly to `uploadObject` like so: `$result = $container->uploadObject($sm_file_path, $tmp_image);`. What happens when you do that?